# How would I call a function's self variable in my game loop?

Tags: python, pygame

I need to call my Level functions "bgX" variable inside of my game loop and then display it onto the screen using my text function, and once they pass a certain point it should cause the player to advance to the next level. However, when I try doing:

```
messageDisplay(str(Level(player).bgX))
```

it doesn't update, and even when I pass the level cap it doesn't make me advance to the next level. Does anyone know why?

Here is my code:

```
import pygame

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 255, 255)

DISPLAY_WIDTH = 800
DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 600
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))

def textObjects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, BLACK)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()
def messageDisplay(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 115)
    textSurf, textRect = textObjects(text, largeText)
    textRect.center = ((DISPLAY_WIDTH/2), (DISPLAY_HEIGHT/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):


        super().__init__()


        width = 100
        height = 150
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(RED)


        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


        self.xVel = 0
        self.yVel = 0


        self.level = None

    def update(self):
        self.calc_grav()


        Level(self).bgX += self.xVel



        correction = 0
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            if self.xVel < 0:
                self.friction()
                correction = self.rect.right - block.rect.left
            elif self.xVel > 0:
                self.friction()
                correction = self.rect.left - block.rect.right

        if correction != 0:
            for block in self.level.platform_list:
                block.rect.x += correction


        self.rect.y += self.yVel


        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            if self.yVel > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            if self.yVel < 0:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom


            self.yVel = 0

            if isinstance(block, MovingPlatform):
                Level(self).bgX += block.xVel

    def calc_grav(self):

        if self.yVel == 0:
            self.yVel = 1
        else:
            self.yVel +=0.3

        if self.rect.y >= DISPLAY_HEIGHT - self.rect.height and self.yVel >= 0:
            self.yVel = 0
            self.rect.y = DISPLAY_HEIGHT - self.rect.height


    def jump(self):
        self.rect.y += 2
        platform_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        self.rect.y -= 2


        if len(platform_hit_list) > 0 or self.rect.bottom >= DISPLAY_HEIGHT:
            self.yVel = -10

    def moveLeft(self):

        self.xVel = 60

    def moveRight(self):

        self.xVel = -60

    def friction(self):

        self.xVel = 0


class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(GREEN)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


class MovingPlatform(Platform):

    xVel = 0
    yVel = 0

    boundary_top = 0
    boundary_bottom = 0
    boundary_left = 0
    boundary_right = 0

    player = None

    level = None

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.xVel
        correction = 0
        hit = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, self.player)
        if hit:
            if self.xVel < 0:
                self.player.friction()
                correction = self.player.rect.right - self.rect.left
            elif self.xVel > 0:
                self.player.friction()
                correction = self.player.rect.left - self.rect.right

        if correction != 0:
            for block in self.level.platform_list:
                block.rect.x += correction

        self.rect.y += self.yVel


        hit = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, self.player)
        if hit:

            if self.yVel < 0:
                self.player.rect.bottom = self.rect.top
            else:
                self.player.rect.top = self.rect.bottom

        if self.rect.bottom > self.boundary_bottom or self.rect.top < self.boundary_top:
            self.yVel *= -1

        cur_pos = self.rect.x - self.level.bgX
        if cur_pos < self.boundary_left or cur_pos > self.boundary_right:
            self.xVel *= -1


class Level(object):

    def __init__(self, player):
        self.platform_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.enemy_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player = player

        self.background = None


        self.bgX = 0
        self.level_limit = -1000

    def update(self):
        self.platform_list.update()
        self.enemy_list.update()

    def draw(self, screen):

        screen.fill(BLUE)


        self.platform_list.draw(screen)
        self.enemy_list.draw(screen)

        for platform in self.platform_list:
            platform.rect.x += self.player.xVel

        for enemy in self.enemy_list:
            enemy.rect.x += self.player.xVel

class Level_01(Level):

    def __init__(self, player):


        Level.__init__(self, player)

        self.level_limit = -1500


        level = [[210, 70, 500, 500],
                 [210, 70, 800, 400],
                 [210, 70, 1000, 500],
                 [210, 70, 1120, 280],
                 ]


        for platform in level:
            block = Platform(platform[0], platform[1])
            block.rect.x = platform[2]
            block.rect.y = platform[3]
            block.player = self.player
            self.platform_list.add(block)


        block = MovingPlatform(70, 40)
        block.rect.x = 1350
        block.rect.y = 280
        block.boundary_left = 1350
        block.boundary_right = 1600
        block.xVel = 1
        block.player = self.player
        block.level = self
        self.platform_list.add(block)


class Level_02(Level):

    def __init__(self, player):

        Level.__init__(self, player)

        self.level_limit = -1000


        level = [[210, 70, 500, 550],
                 [210, 70, 800, 400],
                 [210, 70, 1000, 500],
                 [210, 70, 1120, 280],
                 ]


        for platform in level:
            block = Platform(platform[0], platform[1])
            block.rect.x = platform[2]
            block.rect.y = platform[3]
            block.player = self.player
            self.platform_list.add(block)

        block = MovingPlatform(70, 70)
        block.rect.x = 1500
        block.rect.y = 300
        block.boundary_top = 100
        block.boundary_bottom = 550
        block.yVel = -1
        block.player = self.player
        block.level = self
        self.platform_list.add(block)


def main():
    pygame.init()


    size = [DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

    pygame.display.set_caption("Platformer with moving platforms")

    player = Player()

    level_list = []
    level_list.append(Level_01(player))

    current_level_no = 0
    current_level = level_list[current_level_no]

    active_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player.level = current_level

    player.rect.x = 350
    player.rect.y = DISPLAY_HEIGHT - player.rect.height
    active_sprite_list.add(player)


    done = False


    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    # -------- Main Program Loop -----------
    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player.moveLeft()
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player.moveRight()
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    player.jump()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and player.xVel > 0:
                    player.friction()
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and player.xVel < 0:
                    player.friction()

        active_sprite_list.update()

        current_level.update()


        current_position = current_level.bgX
        if current_position < current_level.level_limit:
            if current_level_no < len(level_list)-1:
                player.rect.x = 350
                current_level_no += 1
                current_level = level_list[current_level_no]
                player.level = current_level
            else:

                done = True


        current_level.draw(screen)
        active_sprite_list.draw(screen)
        messageDisplay(str(Level(player).bgX))


        clock.tick(60)


        pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You're calling `Level(self)` every where which is creating a new instance of the `Level` class. You need to assign an instance of this class somewhere and update it's bgX attr, not create a new instance every time

Comment: [mcve] please, especially minimal.

Comment: @Julien alright I'll see what I can do

Comment: @IainShelvington Do you have any recommendations as to where I should put it?

Comment: You already have `self.level` on the `Player` class, maybe there?

Comment: @IainShelvington How and where would I update the bgX attribute? Sorry If this should be obvious, I'm relatively new to python.

Comment: @IainShelvington WAIT IT WORKED THANK YOU SO MUCH. Can you post an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: OMG AND IT FIXES MY PLATFORM BUG TYSMMM

Comment: @BenDover I believe you can answer your own question, no? Is the code in your post the fixed version?

Comment: @AMC alright I guess I will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was because I was calling Level(self) which created a new instance of the Level class which caused it to continually redefine bgX or something. I simply changed the

```
if isinstance(block, MovingPlatform):
    Level(self).bgX += block.xVel
```

in the player class to self.level.bgX as well as all the other Level(self).bgX's

Credit goes to Iain Shelvington.

Comment: You've identified what the problem is, could you complete the solution by adding what you did to fix it?  This could help other people who have made similar mistakes in object oriented languages in general, Python in particular.

Comment: Are you sure that solves your problem?  The way your code reads here will create a temporary new Level object and add a value to the bgX value, then as soon as the statement completes, the temporary object disappears.  You need to create a more permanent object by creating a reference to it.  Perhaps your `Level(self).bgX` should really read `self.level.bgX`?  In fact, where you have `messageDisplay(str(Level(player).bgX))` it will always print 0, because that is the initialized value of bgX in a Level object.  Prove this by setting bgX to a different number in the Level.__init__ function.

Comment: @RufusVS Can you also help me with my most recent question? Sorry, but I haven't gotten an answer so far, and I don't know what to do

Comment: where/what is your most recent question?  You should learn to add ***links*** to your comments so it is easy to jump to other urls.

Comment: also, you should add at least a few comments in your code to explain what the objects and functions are, and what they do.

Comment: @RufusVS Alright, my newest post highlights only the parts that should be useful in my problem. Here is the link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59525136/how-would-i-fix-my-characters-position-after-hitting-a-block

Comment: I posted an answer on the linked question.